# Map element in plsql and then sort

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, plsql

My problem is I have a database column let's call x.

x values are 0,1,2,3 . In my java application every number has own value like:

```
0 - expire
1 - approval
2 - pending
3 - counting
```

What I need to do is select from database records sorted by related to them string values

So in case above select results will be:

```
1 - approval , 
3 - counting,
0 - expire
2 - pending.
```

I must add that sorting in java is impossible, so I need to sort records in the plsql site.

Can anybody help me how to perform that kind of query,

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can you `CASE` expression or `decode()` function in the `order by` clause to do the custom ordering:

```
-- sampe of data from 0 to 3
SQL> with t1(x) as(
  2    select level - 1
  3      from dual
  4    connect by level <= 4
  5  )
  6  select *  -- actual query
  7    from t1
  8   order by case x
  9              when 0 then 'expire'
 10              when 1 then 'approval'
 11              when 2 then 'pending'
 12              when 3 then 'counting'
 13            end
 14  ;
         X
----------
         1
         3
         0
         2
```